# JQuery Autocomplete (Pengoworks Version) findValue() Function - How To Use

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I've successfully implemented the PengoWorks version of JQuery's autocomplete many times for lookups, etc. but now I'm trying to use it on an add/edit screen where if the autocomplete box has a value already set, it checks against the ajax driven lookup to see if the value exists, and if it does, leaves it as-is and allows the user if they wish to change it to another value from the autocomplete list.

According to the [Documentation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete_docs.txt), I should be able to do this by invoking the findValue() function - however, I can't seem to get it to work - every time I load my page, my preset value in the input is wiped out by the autocomplete, even though the value matches what's in the autocomplete list. I tried using the code from viewing the source on the [demo page](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm), but nothing happens, and no JS errors in Firebug either. I did notice my use of the mustMatch setting seems to affect it (although I would think since it is a match, that shouldn't matter), and removing it causes the preset value in the input to show, but now there exists a possibility the user could enter a value not in the autocomplete list.

Here's my code (sans the findValue() function - I removed it in hopes I wouldn't confuse anyone with having it in, and someone reading the documentation and examples will see something I didn't and point me in the right direction.) Hopefully someone can show me how to use the findValue() function so if the preset value matches an entry in the list, it stays visible, but still allows a user to clear out the input and select another entry from the autocomplete list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#Entity').autocomplete("/validate/getEntities.cfm", { 
                    autofill:true,
                    minChars: 2,
                    matchSubset:true,
                    matchContains:1,
                    selectFirst:true,
                    //mustMatch:true,
                    cellSeparator:"^",
                    onItemSelect:setEntityID
            });

        function setEntityID(li){
            $('#EntityID').setValue(li.extra[0]);
        };
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you use onFindValue callback function?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I removed it as I could not get it to work and wanted someone to instruct me in the proper use of it, as the demo and source from the creator's site doesn't (for me) clearly illustrate it's use.

Comment: Not findValue(), Im asking about the onFindValue callback function.. "the findValue() function does not return a value. Instead, you need to specific a onFindValue callback function that will run. "

Comment: Ah, I see - in the demo, they call findValue() from the onFindValue attribute, but as I originally said, I tried this and it did not work as expected. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Dude the same problem is for me, there is a problem with call back in this plug-in, I can't solve this point either.